# Supported regex escape sequences in grep

Tags: regex, linux, unix, grep

I was trying to use `\s` for specifying *while spaces* in `grep` regex, but it seems grep doesn't recognize it. `grep -E` or `egrep` also didn't work with it.

Here are my trials:

```
$ echo '   foo' | grep '^ *foo'
   foo
$ echo '   foo' | grep '^\s*foo'  <-- **No Output**
$ echo '   foo' | grep -E '^\s*foo'  <-- **No Output**
$ echo '   foo' | egrep '^\s*foo'  <-- **No Output**
$ echo '   foo' | grep '^[[:space:]]*foo'
   foo
```

I also noticed that it recognizes `\w` but not `\d` !

**Que 1.** Is it possible to make `grep` recognize `\s` ?

**Que 2.** Where do I find a list supported regex escape sequences in `grep` ?

**OS** : `RHEL5`

**Shell** : Tried `sh`, `bash`, `tcsh`

```
$ grep --version
grep (GNU grep) 2.5.1
```

**EDIT**

I tried using `grep -P` as suggested in answers, but unfortunately it's not working on my system throwing following error:

```
$ echo '   foo' | grep -P '^\s*foo'
grep: The -P option is not supported   <-- **ERROR**
```

Comment: Just FYI... In PERL grep() accepts \s. I have tried the below program in PERL and it is working fine. `my @Arr = ("  Test", "Test");

@Arr = grep {$_ =~ /^\s+Test/} @Arr;

print "@Arr";
` Output: "     Test"

Comment: @Anand Yes. I notice that grep in PERL works fine. My intention is to make it work on linux shell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No grep or egrep doesn't recognize `\s` or `\d` (PCRE specific constructs) because it uses ERE. See this reference guide:

[**`POSIX and ERE Regex`**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/basic_extended.html)

Though if you use `grep -P` then all PCRE features are recognized.

e.g.

```
echo '   foo' | grep -P '^\s*foo'
   foo
```

Comment: Unfortunately `-P` option is not working on my system. `grep: The -P option is not supported`

Comment: @jkshah: I am sure you can get gnu grep on RHEL via RPMs

Comment: Otherwise you will need to use POSIX: `grep '^[[:space:]]*foo'`

Comment: I could already use ` *` and `[[:space:]]*`. I am not stuck but this question was out of curiosity. I have `grep (GNU grep) 2.5.1` and since I am on enterprise OS, I don't have rights to install anything new! Thanks for your responses!

Answer (score 2):

> Que 1. Is it possible to make grep recognize \s ?

Use Perl regex mode:

```
echo '   foo' | grep -P '^\s*foo'
```

> Que 2. Where do I find a list supported regex escape sequences in grep ?

```
man grep
```

There it says, e.g.:

> The symbols \< and > respectively match the empty string at the beginning and end of a word.  The symbol \b matches the empty string at the edge of a word,  and  \B
>   matches the empty string provided it's not at the edge of a word.  The symbol \w is a synonym for [*[:alnum:]] and \W is a synonym for [^*[:alnum:]].

No other [a-zA-Z] is mentioned

version:

```
grep (GNU grep) 2.14
```

on Debian

Comment: Unfortunately -P option is not working on my system. grep: The -P option is not supported. Updated question